# 2000s novel with dragons and a boy with a book

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I don't remember the name of it at all, and the only bits of the novel itself that I remember was that there was a boy (can't remember his age) and he got a book. And like, once in a while, the book (that I'm reading, not the boy's in the novel) would have flashbacks to a time where there were no dragons, or something similar to that, and a boy found a dragon egg and he had to take it somewhere because people would be going after him for the egg?

I vaguely recall the cover of the book being like... black with a red circle?

I don't think it was *Eragon*, but at the same time, it might be. But I don't think so. I don't remember the author's name, either. I read it maybe... 4-6 years ago and would take it out of my library once in a while.

Comment: Can you remember anything about the boy (his name, race, distinguishing features) Can you remember anything else about the novel like the setting, was it gritty and dark or light and fantastical, for instance? Was there magic in the world other than dragons? Was it illustrated?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/113436.Eragon?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/732897.Dragon_s_Egg (the cover fits - http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1348859247l/732897.jpg)

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17606823-secret-of-the-crystal-dragon

Comment: I don't recall much else about the boy, other than he had found what turned out to be a dragon egg and he had to leave by the advice of an old man (I think he was old, anyway lol). It wasn't illustrated, and the setting was like.. medieval with a fantasy touch to it, if that makes any sense? Though, the most I recall about the book was the sections of it that went to the boy and the egg once in a while. I checked the suggestions you gave, and the closest was Eragon, but I know it wasn't that one.

Comment: It's sounding a lot like Eragon to me.

Comment: Hm. Well, looking at the book covers online for Eragon, the one that I remember seeing isn't there at all, which makes me feel it really isn't Eragon. I'm going to head to my library tomorrow and see if I can find it again, though :) if I can't, I'll still be searching for it, haha.

Comment: Eragon only has the egg for a very short period:, so I'd agree that if your overwhelming memory is of taking a journey with the egg, that doesn't sound like Eragon: it also doesn't have much in the way of cutscenes to a time pre-dragon.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the book today :)

It's a novel called *Endymion Spring* and below is the cover. So I was right with the red and the dragon, though I'm not sure where I got the circle part for the cover.

[image: Endymion Spring cover]

But yes, I found it and I'm very glad :) I read the inside cover and there's a boy with a book from the library and something about a journey from centuries ago.

Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11332176-endymion-spring):

> In the dead of night, a cloaked figure drags a heavy box through snowcovered streets. The chest can only be opened when the fangs of its serpent’s-head clasp taste blood.
>
> Centuries later, in an Oxford library, a boy touches a strange book and feels something pierce his finger. The volume is wordless, but fine veins run through its pages, and they seem to quiver, as if alive. Words begin to appear in the book—words only the boy can see.

If I remember it right, it was a pretty decent book, so it might be an interesting read for others :)

Comment: In about two days, you should be able to answer your own question. :)